# Selecting a Polygon based on the location of a point

Tags: polygon, arcgis-desktop, select

Currently I have a polygon layer made up of three shapes. All the shapes are listed in the attribute table. One of these three shapes intersects a point. I would like to select just the shape that has an intersection of that point.

I am guessing I use the select tool with a piece of code to select the correct shape?

Thanks for reading

Daniel

Comment: Have you tried using 'select by Location?' http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000002q000000 It is one of the most fundamental tools in ArcMap.

Comment: Sounds like @DevdattaTengshe should transfer his Comment to an Answer so that you have the opportunity to Accept it :-)

Comment: @PolyGeo I feel embarrassed to gain rep from an comment like this.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe I'm sure you've worked hard for no acknowledgement many times and it would be good to get another Question with an Answer accepted for the sites stats

Comment: @PolyGeo: I have answered this question, but I don't think there is much chance of the OP coming back and accepting the answer after 2 months.

Answer (score 1):

This was literally my second task when I was taught the use of ArcGIS Desktop.
The '[Select by Location](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000002q000000)' tool is to be used for this purposes.

You should add the featureclasses of both the polygon & the point in ArcMap. Once that is done,  Go to Selections>>Select By Location and select your polygon layer as the target and the points as your source layer. You can use 'intersect' as the operation.

This is a screenshot of the dialog box in ArcGIS Desktop 9.3.1. The dialog for 10.0 and onwards is quite similar.:

[image: Image from 9.3.1]